# error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Xbox 360 SDK\bin\win32\xbreboot.exe"" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, xbox360

I am developing a Xbox 360 app in Visual Studio 2010. When I try to run the starter code even without modifying the program in any way, I get the following error:

> error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Xbox 360
>   SDK\bin\win32\xbreboot.exe"" exited with code 1.

The error occurs at line 1157 which has this line of code:

```
<Target Name="RebootXbox">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(XDKPath)\bin\win32\xbreboot.exe&quot;" />
</Target>
```

I tried running the app with admin privileges but am still getting the error.

---

From the output window, I get the message:

> xbreboot: No address for Xbox 360 development kit has been set

How and where do I set the address?

Comment: Look in the Output window for a more specific error message from xbreboot.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

From the Xbox 360 Neighborhood, right click on the Xbox and select 'Set as Default'. That solves the problem.